# how to restrict cross origin request for other domains using CORs

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, cross-domain

I  am working on asp.net web api project I want  allow only my domain access but its working fine when i calling my webapi from JavaScript  but problem is when i calling web api from c# code it allows any domine to access how can i restrict this   i want give access  only for my domain

**I  am working on asp.net web api project I want  allow only my domain access but its working fine when i calling my webapi from JavaScript  but problem is when i calling web api from c# code it allows all domine to access how can i restrict this..?   i want give access  only for my domain**

Comment: You can't with CORS - server code has no concept of CORS

Comment: thanks ..! then how can i restrict Cors  using server code  presently i am using asp.net  C#

Comment: what do you want to achieve by `"restricting Cors using server code"` .... CORS restricts browser access to cross origin resources ...but you said `problem is when i calling web api from c#` - that involves exactly zero browsers - do you know that your question is?

Comment: CORS is entirely enforced by the browser in response to CORS headers sent from the server. It's up to the client whether it wants to obey CORS or not, so you can't use this to prevent other clients accessing your API.

Comment: is there any other way to prevent  Accessing Api for other  Client .. means i want give security to my Api   and i want allow only  some domain to access my Api and for other domain i want to restrict

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors, a Nuget package from Microsoft.
Follow these step:

1. install package for your API project.
2. add one line code to your **App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs** file to enable the function: config.EnableCors();

   ```
   using System.Web.Http;
   namespace WebService
   {
       public static class WebApiConfig
       {
           public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
           {
               // New code
               config.EnableCors();
               config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                   name: "DefaultApi",
                   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
               );
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. use attribute in your controller or action like this:

   ```
   using System.Net.Http;
   using System.Web.Http;
   using System.Web.Http.Cors;
   namespace WebService.Controllers
   {
       [EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebclient.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
       public class TestController : ApiController
       {
           // Controller methods not shown...
       }
   }
   ```

You can get more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

1=>  `var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://mydomain", "*", "*"); config.EnableCors(cors);`
I wrote this code in web config file as global level  but its working fine when I am calling my web api from client side  its allowing only  for specified domain

2=> This is my Client side code

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$ $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:49676/Account/ValidLogin",
                method: "get",
                data: Employee,
                dataType: "json",
                //contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    GetAllEmployee(data);

                    alert("success");
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    alert("error");
                }
```

3. **I wrote some code I web config file to restrict  other domain request but when  i calling web api by client side it allowing any domine to access so my problem is I want to restrict my api form Other public domain**

Here is my server side code

protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        string strUrl = string.Format("http://mydomain/account/validlogin?username=admin&password=admin");
        HttpWebRequest requestObjectGet = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(strUrl);
        requestObjectGet.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse responseObjectGet = null;
        responseObjectGet = (HttpWebResponse)requestObjectGet.GetResponse();

        string strresulttest = null;

        using (Stream stream = responseObjectGet.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            strresulttest = sr.ReadToEnd();
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string StrToken = js.Deserialize<string>(strresulttest);
            Session["ApiToken"] = StrToken;
```

}